# What's the best way to use possessive pronouns in the Feed Dialog with the JavaScript SDK?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, dialog, feed, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to personalise the caption part of the dialog in an FB Feed Dialog.

The `caption` needs to read something like:

`{*actor*} just entered his/her tip`

...where `his/her` should be the possessive pronoun for the logged in user.

I assumed that there would be a token I could use and FB would substitute it correct (à la the old `<fb:pronoun possessive="true">` from FBML days), however I can't find any mention in the database.

My second thought was to get the user's profile data (I have an access token) and switch based on the `gender` attribute, however this seems a bit long-winded.

If there's no quick and easy way, then I guess I'll just use "their"!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have just answered yourself. 1) check the user gender 2) use alternative phrase like: `{*actor*} just entered a tip` or `{*actor*} just entered their tip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my approach in the end:

```
var callback = function (profile)
{
  switch(profile.gender)
  {
    case 'male':
      pronoun = 'his';
      break;
    case 'female':
      pronoun = 'her';
      break;
    default:
      pronoun = 'their';
      break;
  }

  params = {
    method:       'feed',
    name:         name,
    caption:      "{*actor*} just entered "+pronoun+" top tip",
    link:         uri,
    picture:      picture,
    description:  description,
    actions:      [{
      name:       'Enter your own',
      link:       uri
    }],
    ref:          'feed'
  };

  FB.ui(params); 
};

FB.api('/me', callback);
```